# Calling button("refresh") on a jQuery mobile button breaks the button style

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamically update the text on a jQuery mobile button. The button is actually a link which is styled as a button.

According to the [jQuery mobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-refresh), you should call `button("refresh")` if you manipulate the button via javascript. However, when I do this, the button's style goes a but crazy - it gets shrunk to half-height and the button looks crap.

[Here's a JS Fiddle which demonstrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/rfdQC/).

The code is essentially as follows:

```
$(function() {
    // Buttonize
    var $button = $("#myCrapButton");
    $button.button();

    // Change text on click
    $button.click(function() {
        $button.text("Awesome Button");
        $button.button("refresh");
    });
});
```

What's more, calling `button("refresh")` causes the javascript error: `Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined`.

**I know that I can work around this problem by manipulating the `.ui-btn-text` `span` that's nested inside the button**; however, this seems like the wrong approach as it requires explicit knowledge of the internal workings of jquery Mobile.

Can anyone tell me how to get the refresh call to work?

Using versions:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 (in the JSFiddle it's 1.3.0 beta but the final has the same behavior).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$("[data-role='button']#buttonID").on("click", function() { //code here });`

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP: Using "on" and "click" in this scenario does the exact same thing (see the [documentation for click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)) - "This method is a shortcut for `.on('click', handler)`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry read to fast and didn't see that you were looking specifically for the refresh functionality. As you hav noticed jQM doesn;t offer that on the anchor tag buttons.

Well an alternative is just to replace the button with a new one and let jQM add the markup as before

- http://jsfiddle.net/rfdQC/4/

JS

```
$(function() {
    // Buttonize
    var $button = $("#myCrapButton");
    var $clone = $button.clone();
    $button.button();

    // Change text on click
    $button.click(function() {
        $clone.text("Awesome Button");
        $clone.button();
        $button.replaceWith($clone);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Original:

You just need to drill down into the added markup that jQM adds.

```
<a id="myCrapButton" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            Click me!
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

You're changing the button text:

```
<a id="myCrapButton" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c">
    Awesome Button
</a>
```

Doing this you loose the added markup jQM needs to display the button.
You need to change the nested span text.

```
$(function() {
    // Buttonize
    var $button = $("#myCrapButton");
    $button.button();

    // Change text on click
    $button.click(function() {
        $button.children().children().text("Awesome Button");
    });
});
```

no refresh needed:

```
<a id="myCrapButton" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            Awesome Button
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/rfdQC/3/

Comment: Was trying to avoid manipulating the DOM directly; plus, the selector is incorrect when the button has an icon (please see my updated answer for longer explanation).

Comment: Question clearly states that he didn't want to drill down into the text and manually update it.

Comment: @DrewFreyling You are correct, a quick comment instead of a down vote would be desired when communicating such mistakes. I updated my answer with another solution

Comment: Ah, thanks @PhillPafford - have to admit I hadn't thought about cloning/replacing the button. Seems like a better alternative to replacing the button text actually; I'll mark this as correct (though still wish "Refresh" worked!)

Comment: @PhillPafford Now it has been corrected I'll remove my downvote. The comment explaining the reason for the downvote appears to be kosher from what I read on meta. Please point me to any examples you have where downvoting an incorrect answer is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind; just found this at the top of the documentation:

> Note: Links styled like buttons have all the same visual options as
>   true form-based buttons below, but there are a few important
>   differences. Link-based buttons aren't part of the button plugin and
>   only just use the underlying buttonMarkup plugin to generate the
>   button styles so the form button methods (enable, disable, refresh)
>   aren't supported. If you need to disable a link-based button (or any
>   element), it's possible to apply the disabled class ui-disabled
>   yourself with JavaScript to achieve the same effect.

Although this doesn't actually solve my problem (of how to update the button text) - at least it answers why the "refresh" method isn't supported.

**Edit:**

I am aware that I can *directly* update the text on the button; I said as much in the original question:

> **I know that I can work around this problem by manipulating the
>   .ui-btn-text span that's nested inside the button**; however, this seems
>   like the wrong approach as it requires explicit knowledge of the
>   internal workings of jquery Mobile.

I was hoping to avoid this solution by somehow getting the "refresh" method to work. However, based on the snippet of documentation that I later found (and have quoted above), I realised that using the "refresh" method was not an option.

Given that; I was still hoping there was another way to update the text on the button without explicitly addressing the generated DOM elements (i.e. by using the jQM API) - but so far as I can see, there's no API method to do so. Updating the DOM elements seems like the only way to achieve the desired result.

Both of the selectors provided by @Phil Pafford (`$(this).find('span span')`) and @OmarNew2PHP (`$button.children().children()`) are (in my opinion) incorrect. Yes, they work perfectly in the example given above, however, if you add an icon to the button:

```
<a id="myCrapButton" href="#" data-icon="delete">Click me!</a>
```

Then jQM adds in an additional `span` to display that icon (anchor tag attributes trimmed for brevity):

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Delete</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Using the selectors above will add the text to **both** of the inner `span` tags. This is another example of why I was hoping to avoid updating the DOM directly - because you can't (and shouldn't have to) predict what jQM is going to generate.

But, at the end of the day, it looks like the best way of updating the text inside the button is using the method I was hoping to avoid:

```
$button.click(function() {
    $(".ui-btn-text", this).text("Awesome Button");
});
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Dude, you are such the man.  Thanks for this follow-up. I hope to be migrating to 1.4 very soon.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on this and finally this worked for me. Kind of clean solution.
So, if you have a javascript which is creating following html within an element

```
<div id="buttonParent">
  <a href='#' id="1_button" data-role="button">Click me</a>
  <a href='#' id="2_button" data-role="button">Another Click me</a>
</div>
```

then calling below will refresh the buttons.

```
jQuery('#buttonParent').trigger('create');
```

Please note below was not working and was giving exceptions.

```
jQuery('#1_button').button('refresh')
```

May help someone else like me. It was a shear waste of time. jqm needs to fix this bug. I had a wrapper around these button for a collapsibleset and refresh on that worked fine but this refresh on button kept throwing errors. It was very annoying.