# How to reload only element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reload only a particular element using jquery

I have a table, that table has submit button at the last column,
whenever I click the refresh button it has to reload only 2 column of a that row.

How can I do this?

here is code I have used:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings(".b1").reload();
  $(this).parent().siblings(".b2").reload();
});
```

But this is not reloading the element of table row.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Define *reload*. Do you mean to reload the page?

Comment: there you go, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259955/calling-buttonrefresh-on-a-jquery-mobile-button-breaks-the-button-style

Comment: You just asked this an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972986/how-to-reload-a-value-in-only-one-row-of-table

Comment: I understand by 'reload only 2 columns' you mean you want to refresh their values. If that is the case, then you will have to make an ajax call to your server to fetch their new values and then load them in the corresponding columns.

Answer (score 5):

A jQuery object does not have a `.reload()` method so you can't reload data with the code you're using.

If the data in the table was loaded dynamically via an ajax call, then you will need to make your own ajax call to retrieve new, updated data and insert it into the table.

If the data was loaded with `.load()` (which uses an ajax call under the covers), then you can call `.load()` again with the same arguments you used the first time.  There is no `.reload()`.

Comment: Because it's Stack Overflow and that's how it works here.

Comment: @Hill - I know full well that downvoting is part of stack overflow, but usually it makes more sense for someone to explain why they downvoted so the person who wrote the post has a chance to improve or correct their answer.  And, in fact, stack overflow works even better when people do explain their downvotes because it provides feedback that encourages people to improve their answers.  I liken a downvote without explanation to putting a kid on timeout, but not telling them why.  It's punishment, but doesn't really do any good because no explanation is provided that can modify future behavior.

Comment: No, in my experience, people drive-by downvote because they're more interested in inflating their ego than actually helping people.  I think the "downvote" system should be completely removed.

Comment: @Hill - I'd just rather see a downvote come with an explanation.  I don't want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.reload()` is not a valid jQuery function.

Just keep doing it the way you were shown in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972986/how-to-reload-a-value-in-only-one-row-of-table).